# Where should I call a method to remove items from a ListView if those items were added through user input from a Popup window?

Tags: java, android, listview

I have the following code in Android Studio. I'm able to open a popup whenever the "+ New Semester" button is clicked and a new semester is added to the Main Activity once the user types in the semester name in the popup and clicks on the "Done" button. Now, I want to implement a method that removes semesters that are no longer wanted. I made a method called `removeSemesters()` that I think that does what I want it to do, I haven't been able to test it because I'm not sure where I need to call that method in order to do what I want it to do. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

```
package com.example.gradecalculator;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Private Fields
    private Dialog d;
    private EditText semesterName;
    private ListView semesterList;
    private ArrayList<String> semesterArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayAdapter<String> semesterAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        d = new Dialog(this);
    }

    // When user clicks on "+ New Semester" button open a popup where the user is prompted to
    // type in the Semester Name and when "Done" is clicked the new semester appears in the Main
    // Activity
    public void newSemesterPopup(View v) {
        TextView closePopup;
        ImageButton doneButton;

        d.setContentView(R.layout.new_semester_popup);

        semesterName = (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.editTextSemesterName);
        semesterList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.semesterList);

        doneButton = (ImageButton) d.findViewById(R.id.doneButton);
        doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addSemesters();
            }
        });

        closePopup = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.exitButton);
        closePopup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                d.dismiss();
            }
        });
        d.show();
    }

    // Adds semesters to Main Activity
    public void addSemesters() {
        String getSemesterName = semesterName.getText().toString();

        if(semesterArray.contains(getSemesterName)) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Semester Name already exists.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(getSemesterName == null || getSemesterName.trim().equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cannot add empty Semester Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            semesterAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, semesterArray);
            semesterList.setAdapter(semesterAdapter);
            semesterAdapter.add(getSemesterName);
            d.dismiss();
        }
    }

    // Removes unwanted semesters from Main Activity
    public void removeSemesters() {
        semesterList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                SparseBooleanArray positionChecker = semesterList.getCheckedItemPositions();
                int counter = semesterList.getCount();

                for(int i = counter - 1; i > 1; i--) {
                    if(positionChecker.get(i)) {
                        semesterAdapter.remove(semesterArray.get(i));
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Semester deleted successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                positionChecker.clear();
                semesterAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    // Opens Main Activity
    public void openMainActivity() {
        Intent main = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by myself so in case anyone needs the answer in the future I'll leave it here.

I added the following to the `onCreate` method and it fixed my problem:

```
semesterName = (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.editTextSemesterName);
semesterList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.semesterList);

removeSemesters();
```

Not a hard fix, I thought of it right after posting the questions. Don't know if this is the most efficient way to do it. If not, feel free to give another answer.